# OctoberCMS. Variable disappears after ajax request

Tags: octobercms

My component template code:

**default.htm:**

```
<div id="filter_variations" style="//display: none;">
{{ form_ajax('onAjaxVariations') }}
    <input type="text" id="var_id" name="Filter[id]" value="">
    <input type="submit">
{{ form_close() }}
</div>
<div id="partial_service">
    {% partial __SELF__ ~ '::service' %}
</div>
```

in partial i try display "service" variable, and dynamic "variations" variable:

```
<h1>{{service.name}}</h1>
<span>Selected variation: variation[0].name</span>
```

and it works

**Component:**
[image]
but if I make a ajax request, variable "service" not display in partial. Why is this happening? And how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax handler is working differently from `page life cycle` in October.

so when you call page it will `initialize page` with all the data and all components with its `life-cycle` methods.

> in-short all data is not initialized in `ajax` request

you want `service` object inside partial so you are using

```
$this->page['service']
```

but its not been initialized  so it will not available in ajax,

> to make it available in page `code section` you need to use `onInit` method.

```
function onInit() {
    $this['service'] = // your logic to get service and assign it;
}
```

now this `service` will available inside your ajax handler

public function onAjaxVariations() {
       // $this->page['service'] will be available and can be passed to view now;
   }

on normal page refresh it works because all `page-cycle function executes`, all `component life-cycle` functions are executed so `$this->page['service']` will be available here.

> all `component life-cycle` functions means your `onRender` function **=>** which calls `prepareVars` **=>** which assigns `$this->page['service']` (**this things are not executed in ajax call**)

### { update Preferred solution }

**If your code is dependent on page code (page lifeCycle)**

> **in-short code is written inside page `markup` or in `code section` and you want to execute it first**
>
> inside your ajax handler method you can use this

```
$this->controller->pageCycle();
```

it will automatically execute all the page code and your all variable will be available now.

```
public function onAjaxVariations() {
    $this->controller->pageCycle();
    // $this->page['service'] will be available
}
```

Comment: I added:
public $service;
public function onInit()
    {   
        $this->service = $this->page['service'];
    }

and define variable:
public function onAjaxVariations() {
        $this->page['variations'] = $this->getVariations();
        $this->page['service'] = $this->service;

        return [
            '#partial_service' => $this->renderPartial('Variations::service')
        ];
    }
but variable empty =(

Comment: `onInit` has to be in page's `code section` not inside of the component

Comment: in markup i setted variable like this: {% set service = builderDetails.record %}
How to do this in the code?