# OctoberCMS get id of component being saved

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am trying to update a table with the path of the uploaded file so that it is easy to email a download link but I cannot seem to get the id.

My component looks like this:

```
public function onAddJob() {
    $manual = new Job();
    $manual->company = Input::get('company_name');
    $manual->ordered_by = Input::get('client_name');
    $manual->ordered_by_email = Input::get('client_email');
    $manual->emergency_no = Input::get('emergency_no');
    $manual->instructions = Input::get('instructions');
    $manual->project_name = Input::get('project_name');
    $manual->fileupload = Input::file('fileuploader');
    $manual->save();
    $this->id = $this->property('id');
    Db::table('manual_jobs')->where('id', $this->id)->update(['path' => $manual->fileupload->getPath()]);
```

Everything saves fine but path is not updated as I am not getting the id correctly, can anyone help show me where I am noobing?

Comment: can you share details how you are passing `property "id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id component is defined by the variable `$primaryKey`  on the model

default the primary key is `'id'` corresponding to a database table field named `id`

You can overwrite the default keyname by setting `$primaryKey` to another key

```
class Foo extends Model {
     $primaryKey = 'foo_id';
}
```

Why i'm explaining this is because you don't need to know the name of the field.

What you can do is:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = 'baz';
$foo->save();

echo $foo->getKey();
echo $foo->getAttribute($foo->getKeyName());
echo $foo->{$foo->primaryKey}
```

They will all print out the newly created primary key on the object.

`getkey()` returns the value of the primary key.
`getKeyName()`  returns the name of the primary key field defined in the model

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a lot simpler than I thought.
What I was looking for was this:

```
$manual->id
```

So the update query looks like this:

```
Db::table('manual_jobs')->where('id', $manual->id)->update(['path' => $manual->fileupload->getPath()]);
```

Comment: hmm that is why i asked how you passed it so we can see what is it and how to handle it :), but anyways its solved.

Answer (score 0):

Its because when you call **`ajax request`** it will not call **`pageCycle`**.

as a `result` your `code in page` will `not executed`.

your code on page may be look like this one

```
{% component 'yourComponent' id=someID %}
```

but this code is `not executed` during `ajax call`

> **to execute page code** during `ajax call` you need to `explicitly` call `$this->controller->pageCycle()`

so new code will look like

```
public function onAddJob() {

    // we are calling page code explicitly 
    $this->controller->pageCycle();

    $manual = new Job();
    $manual->company = Input::get('company_name');
    $manual->ordered_by = Input::get('client_name');
    ... other code
}
```

refer this answer as well

Link : [OctoberCMS. Variable disappears after ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199529/octobercms-variable-disappears-after-ajax-request/48200882#48200882)

if you still find issue please comment.